# Django - How to display table/rows of data dynamically from selected value from dropdown

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

It's me again, Django newbie.

I am trying to display related rows/information through an html table from a value selected from dropdowm from an add py form.

e.g. I got a form from employee model. I select employee 1 from an LOV which came from employee model. Employee 1 is fk for skill model. After selecting employee 1 from dropdown, a table will display below listing all the skills that employee 1 has, which is from skill model.

These are what I got so far. I can't find any other useful references online that fits this specific requirement esp. how I wrote and structured my code so far. I am really lost.  I am really on a stump. I don't know where and how to start.

***Snippets:***

**employee_form.html**

```
{% extends 'skillsMatrixApp/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Add Employee{% endblock %}
{% block employee_active %}active{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% if error_message %}
        <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
    {% endif %}
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% include 'skillsMatrixApp/form-template.html' %}
        <div class="form-group sub">
            <div class="col-sm" style="text-align: right">
                <button type="submit" formnovalidate class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
                <button type="submit" formnovalidate name="another" class="btn btn-info">Save and add another</button>
                <button type="submit" formnovalidate name="cancel" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**form-template.html**

```
<div class="form-tmp ">
    {% for field in form %}
        <!--<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }}</span>
            </div>
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">{{ field }}</div>
        </div>-->
        <div class="form-lbl"> {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
            <div class="error">{{ field.errors }}
            </div>
        </div>

    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
class skillsMatrixCreate(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = skillsMatrix
    fields = ['skillsMatrixEmployee', 'skillsMatrixSkills', 'proficiency', 'levelOfInterest']

    success_url = reverse_lazy('skillsMatrixApp:skills-matrix')
    success_message = "Skill associated to Employee successfully."

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if "cancel" in request.POST:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('skillsMatrixApp:index'))
        return super(skillsMatrixCreate, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        if "another" in self.request.POST:
            return reverse('skillsMatrixApp:skills-matrix-add')
        # else return the default `success_url`
        return super(skillsMatrixCreate, self).get_success_url()
```

**urls.py**

```
    url(r'skills-matrix/$', views.skillsMatrixView.as_view(), name='skills-matrix'),
    url(r'skills-matrix/add/$', views.skillsMatrixCreate.as_view(), name='skills-matrix-add'),
    url(r'skills-matrix/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.skillsMatrixUpdate.as_view(), name='skills-matrix-update'),
    url(r'skills-matrix/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.skillsMatrixDelete.as_view(), name='skills-matrix-delete'),
]
```

Please help.

Any help, tips, advice would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically on a web page means that you need to use AJAX calls.
Just put a javascript listener on the dropdown that catch the value of the selected employee.

```
<select id="selectXX" onchange="displaySkills(this)">
```

displaySkills should send an AJAX request to the server to retreive the list of skills and display them in a table or whatever.
In the django side create a function that takes employee as argument and returns the list of the skills, preferably in JSON format. and finally create a route that you ll use in the request.

Comment: How do I put JS listener on the dropdown when it comes directly from the {% for field in form %} attribute from django. This automatically handles all the columns from the table/model I have created. Please help.

Comment: you can add the `onchange` attribute in the form class definition using widgets
`forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'onchange':'displaySkills(this)'}))` and it will render it in the form